# Rails engine: NameError: uninitialized constant Active****. Using require 'active_***' acceptable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm working with a rails engine which uses ActiveRecord/ActiveJob and getting an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveJob
```

To fix this, within the engine.rb I added a require e.g.

```
require 'active_job'

module MyMod
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  ...
```

However it has been suggested to me that this is a bad way to solve the problem and that an alternative is to check that the Constant is defined instead within the affected method call. e.g. if defined?(ActiveJob). I am less happy with that solution.

Can anyone suggest any resources that discuss this, suggest why 'require' may be bad, or suggest alternate solutions?

EDIT: I should state that both solutions actually fix the problem; its as much a matter of understanding why within a Rails engine the Rails classes (e.g. ActiveRecord/ActiveJob) are not available unless explicitly required (which I suspect is simply that an engines dependencies are not autoloaded) and how 'best' to make them available within the engine itself.

Comment: try to add a `gem 'active_job'` in `*.gemspec` file

Comment: Sounds like you should be deferring whatever you're doing with activejob until later in the boot process.

Comment: @FrederickCheung the Name error is raised when the class is declared and in this instance it is simply a case of the class inheriting from ActiveJob.

Comment: I wouldn't be doing that in engine.rb, but without seeing what you are doing I am only speculating

Comment: @ FrederickCheung indeed I am not doing that within the engine itself. In another file is: class Foo < ActiveJob ...blah blah end and this is what raises the NameError.